# Instalar extensiones PHP no se activan y no funcionan

Tags: php

Llevo 1 día intentando instalar extensiones para PHP, trabajo con XAMPP y para la consola ocupo LARAGON con la version de PHP 7.4, el tema es que hago los pasos pero no pasa nada sigue sin funcionarme las nuevas extensiones.

**Ubicación php/ext**
Lo que esta en amarillo son los DLL nuevos que voy a instalar y ninguno me funciona.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Archivo php.ini**
Lo tengo puesto asi

```
extension=mbstring
; NO FUNCIONA
extension=mailparse  
;extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=odbc
extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
;extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop
; NO FUNCIONA
extension=php_imagick.dll
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Reinicio despues Apache pero no hay caso verifico en comando y no se porque no funciona, estoy empezando a odiar a PHP.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Debes estar completamente seguro que tienes instalada la extensión en la ruta adecuada, suponiendo que tienes instalado laragon en `C:/Laragon` la carpeta  de tus extensiones debe estar en la ruta: `C:\laragon\bin\php\php-(TU-VER-DE-PHP)\ext`, así que ve a esa ruta y verifica que las extensiones que estas activando se encuentran alli.

**2.** Luego que verifiques que los archivos están alli debes modificar tu php.ini el que se encuentra en la ruta: `C:\laragon\bin\php\php-(TU-VER-DE-PHP)`.

**3.** Una vez que lo abras debes buscar `extension_dir =  "C:/laragon/bin/php/php-(TU-VER-DE-PHP)/ext"` Y te verificas que estés apunta a la ruta correcta.

**Nota Adicional**

Si tu php.ini está configurado de forma correcta y las extensiones se encuentran en tu carpeta es muy posible que hayas descargado las extensiones que no son compatibles con tu versión de PHP.

Comment: Pues capaz sea lo de la versiones como dices, voy a seguir probando con otras versiones.

Comment: Verifica que la versión de php que tienes cargada en tus variables de entorno es la correcta.